# 'Update' in model results in overwriting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, nested-loops

I have a code here to update a field in database which is null initially.

```
        dumlist=['ss','bb']
        for ntn in imggetvalues:
            for datas in dumlist:
                imgget.update(data=datas)
```

where imgget gives objects of the Django ORM

```
imgget=Model.objects.filter(page_num=3)
imggetvalues=[smtng for smtng in imgget]
```

But this code only overwrites the previous entry as the inner loop runs.
How can I get 1st value from **dumlist** to update 1st field in model object and 2nd in 2nd field,considering there are 2 objects?

Comment: You're using QuerySet.update, which does indeed do mass updating.

Comment: How can I update single field on an object from the list and the next field by next element?

Comment: So you'll need to be obj1.data = 'ss' and obj2.data = 'bb'?

Comment: If I understand right then you have to use `zip` (or `from collections import zip_longest` when both lists could have unequal lengths) such that `for obj, value in zip(imggetvalues, dumlist)` gives you a generator of `(obj1, 'ss')`, then `(obj2, 'bb')`. But update in that case should be through `obj.data = value; obj.save()`